# format html output from xjs

Tags: html, reactjs, webpack, jsx

I have this react component

```
var Page = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>{this.props.title}</title>
        </head>
        <body>
          <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
          <BCCLabel title="aaa"></BCCLabel>
        </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = function render(locals, callback) {
  var html = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(React.createElement(Page, locals))
  callback(null, '<!DOCTYPE html>\n' + html)
};
```

the output html looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><title></title></head><body><h1></h1><div><bcc:label title="aaa">Some text</bcc:label></div></body></html>
```

Not very human-readable. Is there a way to format this html output? Couldn't find a webpack plugin like gulp prettify. I think part of the reason it's doing this is because bbbc:label looks like:

```
render: function() {
    return (<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
      __html: '<bcc:label title="' + this.props.title + '">Some text</bcc:label>'
    }}/>);
  }
```

Comment: I don't know of a way to force that. Why do you want it pretty? The browser doesn't care and you should be editing the JSX code, not the generated HTML.

Comment: Since `renderToStaticMarkup` returns a string literal, it's just going to emit one long string of characters, as we can see. For formatting, check out `htmltidy` up on NPM. Seems to do exactly what you'd need. https://www.npmjs.com/package/htmltidy

Comment: I think, now, it's probably unnecessary. Someone asked me to do it for a reason that requires more explanation than I want to type here. Thanks for the help.